# MySQL Encoding Issue - Different results from windows to linux

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a MySQL database hosted on a windows server. When I query for a particular record from various windows machines using mysql console I get `PÃ¤ivi` (incorrect). When I query for the same record from various *nix machines using mysql console I get `Päivi` (correct). The query I'm using is a simple `SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE id = 12345;`.

My database collation is utf8, the field collation is utf8, and I've tried using `set names 'utf8';` prior to running my queries.

Why would the windows machines return a different result? Could windows be missing certain characters? Is this normal/expected behavior? I'm not an encoding nor language expert so any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: How are you interacting with the servers? Mysql command line, MySQL Workbench, PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @Traroth All my queries were performed via mysql console. I figured it removed the most variables (as opposed to looking at it through PHPMyAdmin where PHP could possibly munge it up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you connect to the server, from the MySQL console client, type the following command to view your current client characterset:

```
status;
```

To set it, use the following command:

```
set names latin1;
```

Comment: Server, Db, Client, and Conn. are all set to utf8 charsets. Isn't that what I want?

Comment: See what it is on the *nix servers and set it the same.

Comment: The client was set to latin on the linux installs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a windows console is still multi-byte using the ANSI code page.  If so that would be the problem.  The results might be correct but the console displays them incorrectly.